# List of Dates in GEE giving wrong results

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

There should be 119 months in the list, but why it gives only 118 months.
How to get 119 months exactly.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fd2f210f8767e4d4c13e70451ddfd173

missing: 2019-02

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2010-01-01');
var secondDate = startDate.advance(1, 'month').millis();
var increase = secondDate.subtract(startDate.millis());
var list = ee.List.sequence(startDate.millis(), ee.Date('2020-01-01').millis(), increase);

var list2 = list.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date);});
print (list2);


List (118 elements)
Date (2010-01-01 00:00:00)
type: Date
value: 1262304000000
1: Date (2010-02-01 00:00:00)
2: Date (2010-03-04 00:00:00)
3: Date (2010-04-04 00:00:00)
4: Date (2010-05-05 00:00:00)
5: Date (2010-06-05 00:00:00)
6: Date (2010-07-06 00:00:00)
7: Date (2010-08-06 00:00:00)
8: Date (2010-09-06 00:00:00)
9: Date (2010-10-07 00:00:00)
10: Date (2010-11-07 00:00:00)
11: Date (2010-12-08 00:00:00)
12: Date (2011-01-08 00:00:00)
13: Date (2011-02-08 00:00:00)
14: Date (2011-03-11 00:00:00)
15: Date (2011-04-11 00:00:00)
16: Date (2011-05-12 00:00:00)
17: Date (2011-06-12 00:00:00)
18: Date (2011-07-13 00:00:00)
19: Date (2011-08-13 00:00:00)
20: Date (2011-09-13 00:00:00)
21: Date (2011-10-14 00:00:00)
22: Date (2011-11-14 00:00:00)
23: Date (2011-12-15 00:00:00)
24: Date (2012-01-15 00:00:00)
25: Date (2012-02-15 00:00:00)
26: Date (2012-03-17 00:00:00)
27: Date (2012-04-17 00:00:00)
28: Date (2012-05-18 00:00:00)
29: Date (2012-06-18 00:00:00)
30: Date (2012-07-19 00:00:00)
31: Date (2012-08-19 00:00:00)
32: Date (2012-09-19 00:00:00)
33: Date (2012-10-20 00:00:00)
34: Date (2012-11-20 00:00:00)
35: Date (2012-12-21 00:00:00)
36: Date (2013-01-21 00:00:00)
37: Date (2013-02-21 00:00:00)
38: Date (2013-03-24 00:00:00)
39: Date (2013-04-24 00:00:00)
40: Date (2013-05-25 00:00:00)
41: Date (2013-06-25 00:00:00)
42: Date (2013-07-26 00:00:00)
43: Date (2013-08-26 00:00:00)
44: Date (2013-09-26 00:00:00)
45: Date (2013-10-27 00:00:00)
46: Date (2013-11-27 00:00:00)
47: Date (2013-12-28 00:00:00)
48: Date (2014-01-28 00:00:00)
49: Date (2014-02-28 00:00:00)
50: Date (2014-03-31 00:00:00)
51: Date (2014-05-01 00:00:00)
52: Date (2014-06-01 00:00:00)
53: Date (2014-07-02 00:00:00)
54: Date (2014-08-02 00:00:00)
55: Date (2014-09-02 00:00:00)
56: Date (2014-10-03 00:00:00)
57: Date (2014-11-03 00:00:00)
58: Date (2014-12-04 00:00:00)
59: Date (2015-01-04 00:00:00)
60: Date (2015-02-04 00:00:00)
61: Date (2015-03-07 00:00:00)
62: Date (2015-04-07 00:00:00)
63: Date (2015-05-08 00:00:00)
64: Date (2015-06-08 00:00:00)
65: Date (2015-07-09 00:00:00)
66: Date (2015-08-09 00:00:00)
67: Date (2015-09-09 00:00:00)
68: Date (2015-10-10 00:00:00)
69: Date (2015-11-10 00:00:00)
70: Date (2015-12-11 00:00:00)
71: Date (2016-01-11 00:00:00)
72: Date (2016-02-11 00:00:00)
73: Date (2016-03-13 00:00:00)
74: Date (2016-04-13 00:00:00)
75: Date (2016-05-14 00:00:00)
76: Date (2016-06-14 00:00:00)
77: Date (2016-07-15 00:00:00)
78: Date (2016-08-15 00:00:00)
79: Date (2016-09-15 00:00:00)
80: Date (2016-10-16 00:00:00)
81: Date (2016-11-16 00:00:00)
82: Date (2016-12-17 00:00:00)
83: Date (2017-01-17 00:00:00)
84: Date (2017-02-17 00:00:00)
85: Date (2017-03-20 00:00:00)
86: Date (2017-04-20 00:00:00)
87: Date (2017-05-21 00:00:00)
88: Date (2017-06-21 00:00:00)
89: Date (2017-07-22 00:00:00)
90: Date (2017-08-22 00:00:00)
91: Date (2017-09-22 00:00:00)
92: Date (2017-10-23 00:00:00)
93: Date (2017-11-23 00:00:00)
94: Date (2017-12-24 00:00:00)
95: Date (2018-01-24 00:00:00)
96: Date (2018-02-24 00:00:00)
97: Date (2018-03-27 00:00:00)
98: Date (2018-04-27 00:00:00)
99: Date (2018-05-28 00:00:00)
100: Date (2018-06-28 00:00:00)
101: Date (2018-07-29 00:00:00)
102: Date (2018-08-29 00:00:00)
103: Date (2018-09-29 00:00:00)
104: Date (2018-10-30 00:00:00)
105: Date (2018-11-30 00:00:00)
106: Date (2018-12-31 00:00:00)
107: Date (2019-01-31 00:00:00)
108: Date (2019-03-03 00:00:00)
109: Date (2019-04-03 00:00:00)
110: Date (2019-05-04 00:00:00)
111: Date (2019-06-04 00:00:00)
112: Date (2019-07-05 00:00:00)
113: Date (2019-08-05 00:00:00)
114: Date (2019-09-05 00:00:00)
115: Date (2019-10-06 00:00:00)
116: Date (2019-11-06 00:00:00)
117: Date (2019-12-07 00:00:00)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused of what you're trying to do. You're doing increments of the number of millis in January, e.g. 31 days. Since there are months with fewer than 31 days, the day of the month you end up in will be later and later the more years you go through. When you end up at 2019-01-31, next increment miss the whole month of February. Maybe you can do something like this:

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2010-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01')
var months = endDate.difference(startDate, 'months')
var list = ee.List.sequence(0, months)
  .map(function (monthOffset) {
    return startDate.advance(ee.Number(monthOffset), 'months')
  })
print(list)
```